# I installed ubuntu 16.04.4 64 bit in virtualbox, but it's showing 32bit after installation

Tags: ubuntu, docker, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

I installed Ubuntu 64 in Oracle VM VirtualBox, however after installation in system settings its showing 32 bit.

This is preventing me from installing docker-ce.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How is it preventing you from installing docker-ce? Are you getting a specific error message? Does the install just terminate? Does it summon Yog Sothoth?

Comment: This is what im getting:

E: No Installation Candidate for docker-ce

According to https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/ I need to be on 64 bit versions of Ubuntu to install Docker CE

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new virtual machine, be sure to choose "Linux" for Type and "Ubuntu (64-bit)" for Version.

After you've created the virtual machine and installed Ubuntu 16.04, you can confirm your installation from the Linux command line with:

```
$ uname -a
```

In the screenshot below, notice the fields in the red box.
[image: Virtual Box Create]